# How to pass a dataframe as a function parameter in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am implementing a program which takes the whole data frame as a parameter. I know this may not be support in Spark, but I would like to know is there a good way to solve my problem.

I have a Spark data frame like this:

```
Item_sale_table 
    item_id   date   Sale Amount 
    aaa       3-11      20
    aaa       3-12      21
    aaa       3-13      28
    ...       ...       ...
    bbb       3-11      17
    bbb       3-12      12
    ...       ...       ...
    ccc       3-11      9
    ...       ...       ...
```

Item_List

```
item_id   description
aaa          xxxx
bbb          xxxyx
ccc          zxsa
...
```

What I want to do, is that get each item from `item_list` table, and collect historical data from `item_sale` table for that item, and apply a function (here is a simple count function) on it.

So the item process function is looks like

```
def ItemProcess (item_id: String, Dataset: DataFrame)  = {

      val item_count = Dataset.filter(Dataset("item_id").contains(item_id)).count()

      println(item_id,item_count)

  }
```

And the main function that call this function is

```
val item_count_collection = item_list.select("item_id").foreach(x => ItemProcess(x(0).toString, item_sale_table))
```

Then I got

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 504)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.resolve(DataFrame.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.col(DataFrame.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.apply(DataFrame.scala:652)
```

So I passed the whole dataframe in the foreach function. I think here is the problem.But how to correct it?

======== Update  =======

I found I would even get `NullPointerException` even if I embed the item process function like this

```
val item_count_collection = item_list.select("item_id").foreach(x => Item_sale_table.filter(Item_sale_table("item_id").contains(x(0).toString)).count())
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate and (optionally) join:

```
val item_counts = item_sale_table.groupBy("item_id").count()
```

Optionally join:

```
item_list.join(item_counts, Seq("item_id"))
```

or with `contains` (way less efficient):

```
item_list.join(
   item_counts,
   item_counts("item_id").contains(item_list("item_id"))),
  "left"
)
```

Comment: but unless using UDF, I can not implement a customized function instead of count, if I use your methods. Am I right?